# How do I organize my icons inside a loop

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a list of icons with labels that comes from a list.
I would like to organize my icons like a main screen of a mobile app where they appear like in a grid.

Right now my icons are like this :

[image]

I would like them to be like this, organized in two colums fixed and records:

[image]

This is My code :

```
  <div class="box">
        <div class="box-body" ng-repeat="x in records" align="center" >
            <a class="btn btn-app">
                <span class="badge bg-yellow">3</span>
                <i class="fa fa-flask"></i> {{x}}
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
```

My Controller :

```
 $scope.records = [
                        "PIA/A",
                        "PIA/C1-Shiftlabo",
                        "PIA/U-MDI",
                        "PIA/V1",
                        "SAP-Lab",
                        "SAP-Lab2",
                        "SAP-Lab3",
                        "SAP-Lab4",
                        "SAP-Lab5",
                ]
```

Comment: What are you using for CSS? Bootstrap ?

Comment: hey Alok, yes indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding ng-repeat on "col-XX-6" div or element. Have a look at the example below.

Is is quite simple if you utilise bootstraps grid system efficiently.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
   {"Name" : "Emails", "Count": 2},
   {"Name" : "Chats", "Count": 4},
   {"Name" : "Messages", "Count": 4},
   {"Name" : "Loads", "Count": 6},
   {"Name" : "Cards", "Count": 3},
   {"Name" : "Points", "Count": 8},]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" ng-repeat="item in items">
         <span class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">
            {{item.Name}}: <span class="badge">{{item.Count}}</span>
          </span>          
         </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3>If you want 3 columns.</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" ng-repeat="item in items">
         <span class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">
            {{item.Name}}: <span class="badge">{{item.Count}}</span>
          </span>          
         </span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```